# Proper Repository Pattern Design in PHP?

Tags: php, database, laravel, repository, repository-pattern

*Preface: I'm attempting to use the repository pattern in an MVC architecture with relational databases.*

I've recently started learning TDD in PHP, and I'm realizing that my database is coupled much too closely with the rest of my application. I've read about repositories and using an [IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) to "inject" it into my controllers. Very cool stuff. But now have some practical questions about repository design. Consider the follow example.

```php
<?php

class DbUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
    }

    public function findByName($name)
    {
    }

    public function create($user)
    {
    }

    public function remove($user)
    {
    }

    public function update($user)
    {
    }
}
```

### Issue #1: Too many fields

All of these find methods use a select all fields (`SELECT *`) approach. However, in my apps, I'm always trying to limit the number of fields I get, as this often adds overhead and slows things down. For those using this pattern, how do you deal with this?

### Issue #2: Too many methods

While this class looks nice right now, I know that in a real-world app I need a lot more methods. For example:

- findAllByNameAndStatus
- findAllInCountry
- findAllWithEmailAddressSet
- findAllByAgeAndGender
- findAllByAgeAndGenderOrderByAge
- Etc.

As you can see, there could be a very, very long list of possible methods. And then if you add in the field selection issue above, the problem worsens. In the past I'd normally just put all this logic right in my controller:

```php
<?php

class MyController
{
    public function users()
    {
        $users = User::select('name, email, status')
            ->byCountry('Canada')->orderBy('name')->rows();

        return View::make('users', array('users' => $users));
    }
}
```

With my repository approach, I don't want to end up with this:

```php
<?php

class MyController
{
    public function users()
    {
        $users = $this->repo->get_first_name_last_name_email_username_status_by_country_order_by_name('Canada');

        return View::make('users', array('users' => $users))
    }

}
```

### Issue #3: Impossible to match an interface

I see the benefit in using interfaces for repositories, so I can swap out my implementation (for testing purposes or other). My understanding of interfaces is that they define a contract that an implementation must follow. This is great until you start adding additional methods to your repositories like `findAllInCountry()`. Now I need to update my interface to also have this method, otherwise, other implementations may not have it, and that could break my application. By this feels insane...a case of the tail wagging the dog.

#### Specification Pattern?

This leads me to believe that repository should only have a fixed number of methods (like `save()`, `remove()`, `find()`, `findAll()`, etc). But then how do I run specific lookups? I've heard of the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), but it seems to me that this only reduces an entire set of records (via `IsSatisfiedBy()`), which clearly has major performance issues if you're pulling from a database.

### Help?

Clearly, I need to rethink things a little when working with repositories. Can anyone enlighten on how this is best handled?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I thought I'd take a crack at answering my own question. What follows is just one way of solving the issues 1-3 in my original question.

*Disclaimer: I may not always use the right terms when describing patterns or techniques. Sorry for that.*

### The Goals:

- Create a complete example of a basic controller for viewing and editing `Users`.
- All code must be fully testable and mockable.
- The controller should have no idea where the data is stored (meaning it can be changed).
- Example to show a SQL implementation (most common).
- For maximum performance, controllers should only receive the data they need—no extra fields.
- Implementation should leverage some type of data mapper for ease of development.
- Implementation should have the ability to perform complex data lookups.

### The Solution

I'm splitting my persistent storage (database) interaction into two categories: **R** (Read) and **CUD** (Create, Update, Delete). My experience has been that reads are really what causes an application to slow down. And while data manipulation (CUD) is actually slower, it happens much less frequently, and is therefore much less of a concern.

**CUD** (Create, Update, Delete) is easy. This will involve working with actual [models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model), which are then passed to my `Repositories` for persistence. Note, my repositories will still provide a Read method, but simply for object creation, not display. More on that later.

**R** (Read) is not so easy. No models here, just [value objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). Use arrays [if you prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130964/database-results-as-objects-or-arrays). These objects may represent a single model or a blend of many models, anything really. These are not very interesting on their own, but how they are generated is. I'm using what I'm calling `Query Objects`.

### The Code:

#### User Model

Let's start simple with our basic user model. Note that there is no ORM extending or database stuff at all. Just pure model glory. Add your getters, setters, validation, whatever.

```
class User
{
    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $gender;
    public $email;
    public $password;
}
```

#### Repository Interface

Before I create my user repository, I want to create my repository interface. This will define the "contract" that repositories must follow in order to be used by my controller. Remember, my controller will not know where the data is actually stored.

Note that my repositories will only every contain these three methods. The `save()` method is responsible for both creating and updating users, simply depending on whether or not the user object has an id set.

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find($id);
    public function save(User $user);
    public function remove(User $user);
}
```

#### SQL Repository Implementation

Now to create my implementation of the interface. As mentioned, my example was going to be with an SQL database. Note the use of a [data mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern) to prevent having to write repetitive SQL queries.

```
class SQLUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        // Find a record with the id = $id
        // from the 'users' table
        // and return it as a User object
        return $this->db->find($id, 'users', 'User');
    }

    public function save(User $user)
    {
        // Insert or update the $user
        // in the 'users' table
        $this->db->save($user, 'users');
    }

    public function remove(User $user)
    {
        // Remove the $user
        // from the 'users' table
        $this->db->remove($user, 'users');
    }
}
```

#### Query Object Interface

Now with **CUD** (Create, Update, Delete) taken care of by our repository, we can focus on the **R** (Read). Query objects are simply an encapsulation of some type of data lookup logic. They are **not** query builders. By abstracting it like our repository we can change it's implementation and test it easier. An example of a Query Object might be an `AllUsersQuery` or `AllActiveUsersQuery`, or even `MostCommonUserFirstNames`.

You may be thinking "can't I just create methods in my repositories for those queries?" Yes, but here is why I'm not doing this:

- My repositories are meant for working with model objects. In a real world app, why would I ever need to get the `password` field if I'm looking to list all my users?
- Repositories are often model specific, yet queries often involve more than one model. So what repository do you put your method in?
- This keeps my repositories very simple—not an bloated class of methods.
- All queries are now organized into their own classes.
- Really, at this point, repositories exist simply to abstract my database layer.

For my example I'll create a query object to lookup "AllUsers". Here is the interface:

```
interface AllUsersQueryInterface
{
    public function fetch($fields);
}
```

#### Query Object Implementation

This is where we can use a data mapper again to help speed up development. Notice that I am allowing one tweak to the returned dataset—the fields. This is about as far as I want to go with manipulating the performed query. Remember, my query objects are not query builders. They simply perform a specific query. However, since I know that I'll probably be using this one a lot, in a number of different situations, I'm giving myself the ability to specify the fields. I never want to return fields I don't need!

```
class AllUsersQuery implements AllUsersQueryInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fetch($fields)
    {
        return $this->db->select($fields)->from('users')->orderBy('last_name, first_name')->rows();
    }
}
```

Before moving on to the controller, I want to show another example to illustrate how powerful this is. Maybe I have a reporting engine and need to create a report for `AllOverdueAccounts`. This could be tricky with my data mapper, and I may want to write some actual `SQL` in this situation. No problem, here is what this query object could look like:

```
class AllOverdueAccountsQuery implements AllOverdueAccountsQueryInterface
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fetch()
    {
        return $this->db->query($this->sql())->rows();
    }

    public function sql()
    {
        return "SELECT...";
    }
}
```

This nicely keeps all my logic for this report in one class, and it's easy to test. I can mock it to my hearts content, or even use a different implementation entirely.

#### The Controller

Now the fun part—bringing all the pieces together. Note that I am using dependency injection. Typically dependencies are injected into the constructor, but I actually prefer to inject them right into my controller methods (routes). This minimizes the controller's object graph, and I actually find it more legible. Note, if you don't like this approach, just use the traditional constructor method.

```
class UsersController
{
    public function index(AllUsersQueryInterface $query)
    {
        // Fetch user data
        $users = $query->fetch(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']);

        // Return view
        return Response::view('all_users.php', ['users' => $users]);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        return Response::view('add_user.php');
    }

    public function insert(UserRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        // Create new user model
        $user = new User;
        $user->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $user->gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $user->email = $_POST['email'];

        // Save the new user
        $repository->save($user);

        // Return the id
        return Response::json(['id' => $user->id]);
    }

    public function view(SpecificUserQueryInterface $query, $id)
    {
        // Load user data
        if (!$user = $query->fetch($id, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'email'])) {
            return Response::notFound();
        }

        // Return view
        return Response::view('view_user.php', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function edit(SpecificUserQueryInterface $query, $id)
    {
        // Load user data
        if (!$user = $query->fetch($id, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'email'])) {
            return Response::notFound();
        }

        // Return view
        return Response::view('edit_user.php', ['user' => $user]);
    }

    public function update(UserRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        // Load user model
        if (!$user = $repository->find($id)) {
            return Response::notFound();
        }

        // Update the user
        $user->first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $user->last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $user->gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $user->email = $_POST['email'];

        // Save the user
        $repository->save($user);

        // Return success
        return true;
    }

    public function delete(UserRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        // Load user model
        if (!$user = $repository->find($id)) {
            return Response::notFound();
        }

        // Delete the user
        $repository->delete($user);

        // Return success
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Final Thoughts:

The important things to note here are that when I'm modifying (creating, updating or deleting) entities, I'm working with real model objects, and performing the persistance through my repositories.

However, when I'm displaying (selecting data and sending it to the views) I'm not working with model objects, but rather plain old value objects. I only select the fields I need, and it's designed so I can maximum my data lookup performance.

My repositories stay very clean, and instead this "mess" is organized into my model queries.

I use a data mapper to help with development, as it's just ridiculous to write repetitive SQL for common tasks. However, you absolutely can write SQL where needed (complicated queries, reporting, etc.). And when you do, it's nicely tucked away into a properly named class.

I'd love to hear your take on my approach!

---

***July 2015 Update:***

I've been asked in the comments where I ended up with all this. Well, not that far off actually. Truthfully, I still don't really like repositories. I find them overkill for basic lookups (especially if you're already using an ORM), and messy when working with more complicated queries.

I generally work with an ActiveRecord style ORM, so most often I'll just reference those models directly throughout my application. However, in situations where I have more complex queries, I'll use query objects to make these more reusable. I should also note that I always inject my models into my methods, making them easier to mock in my tests.

Comment: Why are you still tightly coupling `Response` with your controller?

Comment: @PeeHaa Simply to keep my examples clean and simple. It's also something people quickly understand.

Comment: @PeeHaa Again, it was to keep the examples simple. It's very common to leave pieces of code out of an example if they don't pertain specifically to the topic at hand. In reality, I would pass in my dependencies.

Comment: Interesting that you split up your Create, Update and Delete from your Read. Thought it would be worth mentioning Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) which formally does just that. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: @Jonathan It's been one and a half year since you answered your own question. I was wondering if you are still happy with your answer and if this is your main solution now for most of your projects? The last few weeks I've been reading allot on repositories and I've seen allot of people have their own interpretation of how it should be implemented. Your calling it query objects, but this an existing pattern right? I think I've seen it being used in other languages.

Comment: @Jonathan: How you handle queries that should fina a user not be "ID" but e.g. by "username" or even more complicated queries with more than one condition?

Comment: @Gizzmo yes I was thinking the same thing. I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to pass in a set of "filter parameters" which could span related models, matching object properties in different ways (i.e. not just equality). Like setting up a sparse context bound to the model before executing the search. I don't want to propagate the eloquent/whatever tools for this up to the controller, so am faced with inventing a new query definition structure. I'm sure there's a pattern for that!

Comment: I wish that frameworks just would put in their documentation the full example of of how this should be used. Cause now people are trying to invent wheels by not knowing how to do the right way.

Comment: Your examples are very simple. In real life applications there are more actions done. Do you put all the logic, loops, whatever in those repository classes also? Or repository classes are simple like models and logic should be in another class, lets say library but not in controller? And then controller injects library, library injects repository, repository injects model?

Comment: @Darius.V Typically a Repository is used to access data (an CRUD operations). All the logic would be best suited in a Service. Take a look at: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1440096/908174) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23595036/908174)

Comment: @Gizzmo Using query objects, you can pass in addition parameters to help with your more complicated queries. For example, you can do this in the constructor: `new Query\ComplexUserLookup($username, $anotherCondition)`. Or, do this via setter methods `$query->setUsername($username);`. You can really design this however it makes sense for your particular application, and I think query objects leave lots of flexibility here.

Comment: @Jonathan This Save method decides by `ID` if it's insert or update. What would you say for pivot tables which has two `ID`s  and maybe (or maybe not) other fields. As I live in a `C#` ecosystem and there is a lot of funny things like `LINQ to Entities`, is there any syntax like them which accepts lambdas for conditioning?

Comment: With this approach there's only one entry point for updating/deleting records. This is fine if it's application logic is dictating which records should be updated/deleted but for data concentric operations this logic is best handled by the underlining persistence layer (SQL excels at this).

Comment: How would Eager-Loading play a part in this? In every application I have written, at some point, we had to implement eager loading; very specific to the controller. Almost never re-usable.

Answer (score 53):

Based on my experience, here are some answers to your questions:

**Q:** How do we deal with bringing back fields we don't need?

**A:** From my experience this really boils down to dealing with complete entities versus ad-hoc queries.

A complete entity is something like a `User` object. It has properties and methods, etc. It's a first class citizen in your codebase.

An ad-hoc query returns some data, but we don't know anything beyond that. As the data gets passed around the application, it is done so without context. Is it a `User`? A `User` with some `Order` information attached? We don't really know.

I prefer working with full entities.

You are right that you will often bring back data you won't use, but you can address this in various ways:

1. Aggressively cache the entities so you only pay the read price once from the database.
2. Spend more time modeling your entities so they have good distinctions between them. (Consider splitting a large entity into two smaller entities, etc.)
3. Consider having multiple versions of entities. You can have a `User` for the back end and maybe a `UserSmall` for AJAX calls. One might have 10 properties and one has 3 properties.

The downsides of working with ad-hoc queries:

1. You end up with essentially the same data across many queries. For example, with a `User`, you'll end up writing essentially the same `select *` for many calls. One call will get 8 of 10 fields, one will get 5 of 10, one will get 7 of 10. Why not replace all with one call that gets 10 out of 10? The reason this is bad is that it is murder to re-factor/test/mock.
2. It becomes very hard to reason at a high level about your code over time. Instead of statements like "Why is the `User` so slow?" you end up tracking down one-off queries and so bug fixes tend to be small and localized.
3. It's really hard to replace the underlying technology. If you store everything in MySQL now and want to move to MongoDB, it's a lot harder to replace 100 ad-hoc calls than it is a handful of entities.

**Q:** I will have too many methods in my repository.

**A:** I haven't really seen any way around this other than consolidating calls. The method calls in your repository really map to features in your application. The more features, the more data specific calls. You can push back on features and try to merge similar calls into one.

The complexity at the end of the day has to exist somewhere. With a repository pattern we've pushed it into the repository interface instead of maybe making a bunch of stored procedures.

Sometimes I have to tell myself, "Well it had to give somewhere! There are no silver bullets."

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. You've got me thinking now. My big concern here is that everything I read says don't `SELECT *`, rather only select the fields you require. For example, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

As for all those ad-hock queries you speak of, I certainly understand where you're coming from. I have a very large app right now that has many of them. That was my "Well it had to give somewhere!" moment, I opted for maximum performance. However, now I'm dealing with LOTS of different queries.

Comment: One follow up thought. I've seen a recommendation to use a R—CUD approach. Since `reads` are often where performance issues arise, you could use a more custom query approach for them, that don't translate into real business objects. Then, for `create`, `update` and `delete`, use an ORM, which works with whole objects. Any thoughts on that approach?

Comment: As a note for using "select *". I've done it in the past and it worked ok - until we hit varchar(max) fields. Those killed our queries. So if you have tables with ints, small text fields, etc. it's not that bad. Feels unnatural, but software goes that way. What was bad is suddenly good and vice versa.

Comment: I haven't heard about the R-CUD approach, but it sounds good! Makes sense to me. I would do some work investigating how you could cache reads with more "full" objects before going down the R-CUD road. I'm curious to see if you have success with it though. There are pros and cons to the various approaches and I've seen the full entity thing work pretty well and I've seen the ad-hoc read stuff work. The real pain with the ad-hoc reads is re-factoring/changing the underlying data store. That's where it has bitten me in the past.

Comment: The R-CUD approach is actually CQRS

Comment: @ryan1234 "The complexity at the end of the day has to exist somewhere."  Thank you for this.  Makes me feel better.

Answer (score 29):

I use the following interfaces:

- `Repository` - loads, inserts, updates and deletes entities
- `Selector` - finds entities based on filters, in a repository
- `Filter` - encapsulates the filtering logic

My `Repository` is database agnostic; in fact it doesn't specify any persistence; it could be anything: SQL database, xml file, remote service, an alien from outer space etc.
For searching capabilities, the `Repository` constructs an `Selector` which can be filtered, `LIMIT`-ed, sorted and counted. In the end, the selector fetches one or more `Entities` from the persistence.

Here is some sample code:

```php
<?php
interface Repository
{
    public function addEntity(Entity $entity);

    public function updateEntity(Entity $entity);

    public function removeEntity(Entity $entity);

    /**
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function loadEntity($entityId);

    public function factoryEntitySelector():Selector
}


interface Selector extends \Countable
{
    public function count();

    /**
     * @return Entity[]
     */
    public function fetchEntities();

    /**
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function fetchEntity();
    public function limit(...$limit);
    public function filter(Filter $filter);
    public function orderBy($column, $ascending = true);
    public function removeFilter($filterName);
}

interface Filter
{
    public function getFilterName();
}
```

Then, one implementation:

```
class SqlEntityRepository
{
    ...
    public function factoryEntitySelector()
    {
        return new SqlSelector($this);
    }
    ...
}

class SqlSelector implements Selector
{
    ...
    private function adaptFilter(Filter $filter):SqlQueryFilter
    {
         return (new SqlSelectorFilterAdapter())->adaptFilter($filter);
    }
    ...
}
class SqlSelectorFilterAdapter
{
    public function adaptFilter(Filter $filter):SqlQueryFilter
    {
        $concreteClass = (new StringRebaser(
            'Filter\\', 'SqlQueryFilter\\'))
            ->rebase(get_class($filter));

        return new $concreteClass($filter);
    }
}
```

The ideea is that the generic `Selector` uses `Filter` but the implementation `SqlSelector` uses `SqlFilter`; the `SqlSelectorFilterAdapter` adapts a generic `Filter` to a concrete `SqlFilter`.

The client code creates `Filter` objects (that are generic filters) but in the concrete implementation of the selector those filters are transformed in SQL filters.

Other selector implementations, like `InMemorySelector`, transform from `Filter` to `InMemoryFilter` using their specific `InMemorySelectorFilterAdapter`; so, every selector implementation comes with its own filter adapter.

Using this strategy my client code (in the bussines layer) doesn't care about a specific repository or selector implementation.

```
/** @var Repository $repository*/
$selector = $repository->factoryEntitySelector();
$selector->filter(new AttributeEquals('activated', 1))->limit(2)->orderBy('username');
$activatedUserCount = $selector->count(); // evaluates to 100, ignores the limit()
$activatedUsers = $selector->fetchEntities();
```

P.S. This is a simplification of my real code

Comment: "Repository - loads, inserts, updates and deletes entities" this is what a "service layer", "DAO", "BLL" can do

Answer (score 5):

I'll add a bit on this as I am currently trying to grasp all of this myself.

### #1 and 2

This is a perfect place for your ORM to do the heavy lifting.  If you are using a model that implements some kind of ORM, you can just use it's methods to take care of these things.  Make your own orderBy functions that implement the Eloquent methods if you need to.  Using Eloquent for instance:

```
class DbUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return User::all();
    }

    public function get(Array $columns)
    {
       return User::select($columns);
    }
```

What you seem to be looking for is an ORM.  No reason your Repository can't be based around one.  This would require User extend eloquent, but I personally don't see that as a problem.

If you do however want to avoid an ORM, you would then have to "roll your own" to get what you're looking for.

### #3

Interfaces aren't supposed be hard and fast requirements. Something can implement an interface and add to it.  What it can't do is fail to implement a required function of that interface.  You can also extend interfaces like classes to keep things DRY.

That said, I'm just starting to get a grasp, but these realizations have helped me.

Comment: What I dislike about this method is that if you had a MongoUserRepository, that and your DbUserRepository would return different objects. Db returning an Eloquent\Model, and Mongo something of its own.

Surely a better implementation is to have both repositories return instances/collections of a separate Entity\User class. This way you aren't mistakingly rely on Eloquent\Model's DB methods when you switch to using the MongoRepository

Comment: I'd definitely agree with you on that one.  What I would probably do to avoid that is never use those methods outside of the Eloquent requiring class.  So the get function probably should be private and only used within the class as it, as you pointed out, would return something that other repositories couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

I can only comment on the way we (at my company) deal with this. First of all performance is not too much of an issue for us, but having clean/proper code is.

First of all we define Models such as a `UserModel` that uses an ORM to create `UserEntity` objects. When a `UserEntity` is loaded from a model all fields are loaded. For fields referencing foreign entities we use the appropriate foreign model to create the respective entities. For those entities the data will be loaded ondemand. Now your initial reaction might be ...???...!!! let me give you an example a bit of an example:

```
class UserEntity extends PersistentEntity
{
    public function getOrders()
    {
        $this->getField('orders'); //OrderModel creates OrderEntities with only the ID's set
    }
}

class UserModel {
    protected $orm;

    public function findUsers(IGetOptions $options = null)
    {
        return $orm->getAllEntities(/*...*/); // Orm creates a list of UserEntities
    }
}

class OrderEntity extends PersistentEntity {} // user your imagination
class OrderModel
{
    public function findOrdersById(array $ids, IGetOptions $options = null)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In our case `$db` is an ORM that is able to load entities. The model instructs the ORM to load a set of entities of a specific type. The ORM contains a mapping and uses that to inject all the fields for that entity in to the entity. For foreign fields however only the id's of those objects are loaded. In this case the `OrderModel` creates `OrderEntity`s with only the id's of the referenced orders. When `PersistentEntity::getField` gets called by the `OrderEntity` the entity instructs it's model to lazy load all the fields into the `OrderEntity`s. All the `OrderEntity`s associated with one UserEntity are treated as one result-set and will be loaded at once.

The magic here is that our model and ORM inject all data into the entities and that entities merely provide wrapper functions for the generic `getField` method supplied by `PersistentEntity`. To summarize we always load all the fields, but fields referencing a foreign entity are loaded when necessary. Just loading a bunch of fields is not really a performance issue. Load all possible foreign entities however would be a HUGE performance decrease.

Now on to loading a specific set of users, based on a where clause. We provide an object oriented package of classes that allow you to specify simple expression that can be glued together. In the example code I named it `GetOptions`. It's a wrapper for all possible options for a select query. It contains a collection of where clauses, a group by clause and everything else. Our where clauses are quite complicated but you could obviously make a simpler version easily.

```
$objOptions->getConditionHolder()->addConditionBind(
    new ConditionBind(
        new Condition('orderProduct.product', ICondition::OPERATOR_IS, $argObjProduct)
    )
);
```

A simplest version of this system would be to pass the WHERE part of the query as a string directly to the model.

I'm sorry for this quite complicated response. I tried to summarize our framework as quickly and clear as possible. If you have any additional questions feel free to ask them and I'll update my answer.

EDIT: Additionally if you really don't want to load some fields right away you could specify a lazy loading option in your ORM mapping. Because all fields are eventually loaded through the `getField` method you could load some fields last minute when that method is called. This is not a very big problem in PHP, but I would not recommend for other systems.

Answer (score 3):

These are some different solutions I've seen. There are pros and cons to each of them, but it is for you to decide.

## Issue #1: Too many fields

This is an important aspect especially when you take in to account [Index-Only Scans](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index). I see two solutions to dealing with this problem. You can update your functions to take in an optional array parameter that would contain a list of a columns to return. If this parameter is empty you'd return all of the columns in the query. This can be a little weird; based off the parameter you could retrieve an object or an array. You could also duplicate all of your functions so that you have two distinct functions that run the same query, but one returns an array of columns and the other returns an object.

```
public function findColumnsById($id, array $columns = array()){
    if (empty($columns)) {
        // use *
    }
}

public function findById($id) {
    $data = $this->findColumnsById($id);
}
```

## Issue #2: Too many methods

I briefly worked with [Propel ORM](http://propelorm.org/) a year ago and this is based off what I can remember from that experience. Propel has the option to generate its class structure based off the existing database schema. It creates two objects for each table. The first object is a long list of access function similar to what you have currently listed; `findByAttribute($attribute_value)`. The next object inherits from this first object. You can update this child object to build in your more complex getter functions.

Another solution would be using `__call()` to map non defined functions to something actionable. Your `__call` method would be would be able to parse the findById and findByName into different queries.

```
public function __call($function, $arguments) {
    if (strpos($function, 'findBy') === 0) {
        $parameter = substr($function, 6, strlen($function));
        // SELECT * FROM $this->table_name WHERE $parameter = $arguments[0]
    }
}
```

I hope this helps at least some what.

Answer (score 1):

> Issue #3: Impossible to match an interface
>
> I see the benefit in using interfaces for repositories, so I can swap
>   out my implementation (for testing purposes or other). My
>   understanding of interfaces is that they define a contract that an
>   implementation must follow. This is great until you start adding
>   additional methods to your repositories like findAllInCountry(). Now I
>   need to update my interface to also have this method, otherwise, other
>   implementations may not have it, and that could break my application.
>   By this feels insane...a case of the tail wagging the dog.

My gut tells me this maybe requires an interface that implements query optimized methods alongside generic methods. Performance sensitive queries should have targeted methods, while infrequent or light-weight queries get handled by a generic handler, maybe the the expense of the controller doing a little more juggling.

The generic methods would allow any query to be implemented, and so would prevent breaking changes during a transition period. The targeted methods allow you to optimize a call when it makes sense to, and it can be applied to multiple service providers.

This approach would be akin to hardware implementations performing specific optimized tasks, while software implementations do the light work or flexible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think [graphQL](https://graphql.org/) is a good candidate in such a case to provide a large scale query language without increasing the complexity of data repositories.

However, there's another solution if you don't want to go for the graphQL for now. By using a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) where an object is used for carring the data between processes, in this case between the service/controller and the repository.

An elegant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39014955/3729946) is already provided above, however I'll try to give another example that I think it's simpler and could serve as a starting point for a new project.

As shown in the code, we would need only 4 methods for CRUD operations. the `find` method would be used for listing and reading by passing object argument.
Backend services could build the defined query object based on a URL query string or based on specific parameters.

The query object (`SomeQueryDto`) could also implement specific interface if needed. and is easy to be extended later without adding complexity.

```
<?php

interface SomeRepositoryInterface
{
    public function create(SomeEnitityInterface $entityData): SomeEnitityInterface;
    public function update(SomeEnitityInterface $entityData): SomeEnitityInterface;
    public function delete(int $id): void;

    public function find(SomeEnitityQueryInterface $query): array;
}

class SomeRepository implements SomeRepositoryInterface
{
    public function find(SomeQueryDto $query): array
    {
        $qb = $this->getQueryBuilder();

        foreach ($query->getSearchParameters() as $attribute) {
            $qb->where($attribute['field'], $attribute['operator'], $attribute['value']);
        }

        return $qb->get();
    }
}

/**
 * Provide query data to search for tickets.
 *
 * @method SomeQueryDto userId(int $id, string $operator = null)
 * @method SomeQueryDto categoryId(int $id, string $operator = null)
 * @method SomeQueryDto completedAt(string $date, string $operator = null)
 */
class SomeQueryDto
{
    /** @var array  */
    const QUERYABLE_FIELDS = [
        'id',
        'subject',
        'user_id',
        'category_id',
        'created_at',
    ];

    /** @var array  */
    const STRING_DB_OPERATORS = [
        'eq' => '=', // Equal to
        'gt' => '>', // Greater than
        'lt' => '<', // Less than
        'gte' => '>=', // Greater than or equal to
        'lte' => '<=', // Less than or equal to
        'ne' => '<>', // Not equal to
        'like' => 'like', // Search similar text
        'in' => 'in', // one of range of values
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $searchParameters = [];

    const DEFAULT_OPERATOR = 'eq';

    /**
     * Build this query object out of query string.
     * ex: id=gt:10&id=lte:20&category_id=in:1,2,3
     */
    public static function buildFromString(string $queryString): SomeQueryDto
    {
        $query = new self();
        parse_str($queryString, $queryFields);

        foreach ($queryFields as $field => $operatorAndValue) {
            [$operator, $value] = explode(':', $operatorAndValue);
            $query->addParameter($field, $operator, $value);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function addParameter(string $field, string $operator, $value): SomeQueryDto
    {
        if (!in_array($field, self::QUERYABLE_FIELDS)) {
            throw new \Exception("$field is invalid query field.");
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($operator, self::STRING_DB_OPERATORS)) {
            throw new \Exception("$operator is invalid query operator.");
        }
        if (!is_scalar($value)) {
            throw new \Exception("$value is invalid query value.");
        }

        array_push(
            $this->searchParameters,
            [
                'field' => $field,
                'operator' => self::STRING_DB_OPERATORS[$operator],
                'value' => $value
            ]
        );

        return $this;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        // camelCase to snake_case
        $field = strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<!^)[A-Z]/', '_$0', $name));

        if (in_array($field, self::QUERYABLE_FIELDS)) {
            return $this->addParameter($field, $arguments[1] ?? self::DEFAULT_OPERATOR, $arguments[0]);
        }
    }

    public function getSearchParameters()
    {
        return $this->searchParameters;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$query = new SomeEnitityQuery();
$query->userId(1)->categoryId(2, 'ne')->createdAt('2020-03-03', 'lte');
$entities = $someRepository->find($query);

// Or by passing the HTTP query string
$query = SomeEnitityQuery::buildFromString('created_at=gte:2020-01-01&category_id=in:1,2,3');
$entities = $someRepository->find($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest https://packagist.org/packages/prettus/l5-repository as vendor to implement Repositories/Criterias etc ... in Laravel5 :D

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ryan1234 that you should pass around complete objects within the code and should use generic query methods to get those objects.

```
Model::where(['attr1' => 'val1'])->get();
```

For external/endpoint usage I really like the GraphQL method.

```
POST /api/graphql
{
    query: {
        Model(attr1: 'val1') {
            attr2
            attr3
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   class Criteria {}
   class Select {}
   class Count {}
   class Delete {}
   class Update {}
   class FieldFilter {}
   class InArrayFilter {}
   // ...

   $crit = new Criteria();  
   $filter = new FieldFilter();
   $filter->set($criteria, $entity, $property, $value);
   $select = new Select($criteria);
   $count = new Count($criteria);
   $count->getRowCount();
   $select->fetchOne(); // fetchAll();
```

So i think