# PHP Constructor Containing Database Query to build object, good/bad?

Tags: php, mysql, class, constructor

Is it bad practice to have a database query in the constructor for a class in order to load it upon creating a new instance of it?

```
class Home
{
    private $home_id = null;
    private $home_name = null;
    private $home_number = null;
    private $home_street = null;

    function __construct($home_id)
    {
        $do_query = $mysql_con->query("SELECT * FROM home WHERE home_id = '$home_id'");

        while ($home_data = $do_query->fetch_assoc())
        {
            // Set all of the items in the object
            $this->home_id = $home_data["home_id"];
            $this->home_name = $home_data["home_name"];
            $this->home_number = $home_data["home_number"];
            $this->home_street = $home_data["home_street"];
        }
    }
}
```

I have been told before that this might be bad practice, to have a query that builds up the object in the constructor.

- If it is bad practice, why is it bad practice?
- What is the alternative?

Comment: Where is `$mysql_con` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Home` class is a domain object and those should ideally not be aware of how they're persisted.

Separating the concerns allows for flexibility. This is also referred to as the Data Mapper pattern.

```
class Home
{
    public $home_id;
    public $home_name;
    public $home_number;
    public $home_street;
}

interface HomeMapperInterface
{
    public function get($id);
}

class HomeMapper implements HomeMapperInterface
{
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query(...);
        if (($row = $do_query->fetch_assoc()) === false) {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException();
        }

        $home = new Home;
        $home->home_id = $row['home_id'];
        // ...

        return $home;
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
$mapper = new HomeMapper($db);
$home = $mapper->get(123);
```

You can improve this by using Identifier Map to avoid loading the same record twice into separate objects.

Btw, this is only a partial data mapper; it would also be used to update, insert and delete objects from your database.

Answer (score 1):

The Repository Pattern is a useful tool to help mitigate this issue, take a look at this previous SO Discussion.

[Proper Repository Pattern Design in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16176990/proper-repository-pattern-design-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be bad practise if you are careful. For example, what happens when the query fails? Does the constructor return a half-baked object or does it throw an exception? Throwing an exception is considered better because operating on half-constructed objects can cause errors that are hard to predict.

Another issue is performance: a database query can be an expensive operation. Some people might be surprised by the constructor taking a long time to complete, but if it's clearly documented there should be no problem.

Another performance issue is batching: if you have to fetch several objects from the database with  a design like this you have to make many separate queries to the database when you could make just one and construct objects based on the results.